# Keeping it DRY when constructor needs to call overridable method

Tags: java, oop, constructor

As per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404301/whats-wrong-with-overridable-method-calls-in-constructors), while I understand why it goes wrong, how can I effectively solve this while keeping my code DRY?  I wouldn't want to copy and paste the contents in that function into the constructor.

Suppose I have the following

```
class Parent
{
    Parent()
    {
        overridableFunction();
    }

    void overridableFunction()
    { ... }
}

class Child extends Parent
{
    Child()
    {
        super();
        overridableFunction()
    }

    void overridableFunction()
    { ... // overridden }
}
```

Ideally, I wish the execution flow of the `Child` constructor to be
`Parent() --> Parent.overridableFunction() --> Child.overridableFunction()`

How can I achieve this without copying and pasting stuff around thus making the code WET?

Answer (score 1):

If you wish `Parent`'s constructor to execute its own implementation of `overridableFunction()` and `Child`'s constructor to execute its own implementation of `overridableFunction()`, what you are basically saying is you don't want `Child`'s `overridableFunction()` to override `Parent`'s `overridableFunction()` method.

You can give the two methods different names, or keep the names identical, but make `Parent`'s method private, to avoid any overriding.

Comment: Wouldn't removing `overridableFunction();`  from `Child` constructor result in `Parent` and `Child` each executing its own implementation of `overridableFunction()` ?

Comment: @c0der Based on what the OP wrote (`Ideally, I wish the execution...`), he wants both methods to be executed when creating an instance of the Child class. Therefore he doesn't want to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you want to do it, but this follows the execution flow you asked for :

```
class Parent
{
    Parent()
    {
        overridableFunction();
    }

    void overridableFunction()
    { System.out.println("Parent implementation "); }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         new Child();
    }
}

class Child extends Parent
{
    Child()
    {
        super();
        //remove overridableFunction();
    }

    @Override
    void overridableFunction()
    {
        super.overridableFunction();
        System.out.println("Child implementation ");
    }
}
```